# xcode "simulator bulid" lost

Tags: xcode

today I suddenly find that my xcode "simulator bulid" lost, I can't bulid apps to simulator target, anybody can help me ,thx a lot! I capture an image, but I can' upload, sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

I post img to flickr. here's the link:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/16857536@N00/5282433324/